# How to change color of progress bar as it progresses?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

It would have been easy with Flex 3 using [barColor](http://polygeek.com/813_flex_changing-the-flex-progressbar-from-red-green) but as barColor is no more available in Flex 4 how can I setup progress bar such that the progress fluid changes it's color with progress.

Like starting progress with the shades of lighter green and ending at bright red.

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question here: [How to dynamically fill a progress bar in Flex/ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945429/how-to-dynamically-fill-a-progress-bar-in-flex-actionscript/4947959#4947959)

In a nutshell, create a custom skin for the progress bar and fill it with a gradient (if I'm understanding you correctly.)  The solution I linked is for a segmented version, but you can just replace the repeating gradient stops with single stops to get a smooth gradient.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Mueller, on second thought, what do you mean by 'segmented version'?

Comment: If you run the code for the example I cited, it will show the progress as one color in the first half of the bar, then another color in the second half, which is what the original questioner wanted.  In your case (if I am understanding correctly), you want the bar to transition gradually from one color to another as it grows.  In that case, you just need two gradient stops in the colors array, one with the beginning color and another with the ending color. The bar as a whole will then gradually change color from end to end.  Does that help?